# Windows Server Shared Printers and Resource Allocation

Tags: windows, printing

I have a questions regarding resources on network printing.

Lets say we have a windows server which has 100+ shared printers and I setup one of them on my laptop as a network printer; when I print a 5000 page document from my laptop on MS Word, does spooling happen on laptop or windows Server?

Basically, I am wondering if the laptop is allocating resources to print this document (not what I want). I would like the server sharing the printer to handle the spooling/resource allocation and print job.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control that - in your laptop's printer properties (assuming you're on some version of Windows also).

Right click the printer icon in the printers folder. Choose Properties. Go to the Advanced tab.  Choose 'print directly to the printer' to prevent local spooling.

Be warned, if the server doesn't do spooling, then your job will be very, very slow and big jobs may fail.